# Some requests have very slow TTFB when using Apache in front of Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server

I deployed a java web application with Tomcat on port 8080, when using Apache for accessing the app on port 80 (ProxyPass), sometimes a random request (JS, CSS, XHR) has a TTFB about 15 seconds. This occurs about 10% of times but when I access the app directly on port 8080 every thing is fine! The problem also occurs when using `iptable` for mapping port 80 to 8080.

Any Idea?